# Imagick: unable to open file

Tags: php, imagick

When simply calling the Imagick class:

```
$image = new Imagick('/images/magick/atmsk.png');
```

I get the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'unable to open file `/images/magick/atmsk.png' @
>   png.c/ReadPNGImage/2889' in .../imag.php:4 Stack trace: #0
>   .../imag.php(4): Imagick->__construct('/images/magick/...') #1 {main}
>   thrown in .../imag.php

I have checked memory available as per another posting here and that is ok!

Comment: what happens if you use the full path to the image file, for instance something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/magick/atmsk.png'`

Comment: Then $image shows Imagick Object !! This was the problem ... thanks for the quick help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the full path to the image, for example:

```
$image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/magick/atmsk.png');
```

Comment: I have tried the following and still get the error: `$im = new Imagick(); $im->readImage(realpath($path));`

Comment: this might come in helpful for some: `$imagemagickisawful=substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], "/") )."/";` then use `$imagemagickisawful.$your_path_you_would_use_otherwise`

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm... Here is my code I have used: But don't forget to mention your Sitename withing the code as follow:

Input: `$im = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/site.com/images/image.jpg');`

Output: `$im->writeImages($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/site.com/images/image.jpg', true);`

and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gmartellino answer and clarification. As I can't add a comment yet, its here incase someone has a similar situation.

In my case I had to access other sub folders in the parent.

The server path would look something like this

```
$path_file = "../other_folder/".$filename.".".$filetype;
```

The URL is

```
$path_file = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']."/other_folder/".$filename.".".$filetype;
```

Hence, the used  path is

```
$path_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/other_folder/".$filename.".".$filetype;
```

When using the `Imagick` class to read a file, use the full system path to the file rather than a URL

Hope it helped.